# Ubuntu 12.04 is not doing normal shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I have installed `Ubuntu 12.04` on my laptop.Every thing is working fine.But from last two days I am facing a problem and that is when I am going to `shutdown my system`,it is showing the `shutdown process` but it is actually `not doing shut down`.`The screen is reaming like that for many time` then I am doing the `forcibly shutdown by pressing the start key of my system`.Can someone tell me what is the wrong going on?Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

**[update]**

When the shutdown process was going on I just pressed the `esc` key and it showed the `error message` like this

```
modem manager[878]:<info>Caught signal 15,is shutting down...        [Fail]
```

Comment: This is a bug, so it needs to be reported on Launchpad as well. That way it'll get fixed quicker.

Comment: so how to report that?

Comment: I don't know whether it is a bug or not as described in RobinJ's comment above, but it is NOT recommend that turn off your Linux system by pressing the power button, in that rude case, you may get your file system broken. (Try fsck command to repair file system of ubuntu) In addition, you can try `sync` ;` sudo shutdown -h now` command in terminal, press `F7` to see logs while shutdown progress to track what's happening.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: @erdemkeren Didn't EXT3 and EXT4 have a bunch of systems to prevent  data corruption when the system was forcefully shut down? I don't deny it's not recommended, but that more for fear of hardware failure.

Comment: any fortune with this issue? It is really boring

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in NVIDIA driver. You have to go to System Settings --> Additional drivers and there you have to mark and install **NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates (version current updates)**.

The Recommended driver above it causes the problem.

Comment: I don't have graphics card installed in my system.

Comment: How do you know he is using nVidia Drivers in the first place.

Comment: It looks like there is a bug for that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/991977 . If you are affected, click on "yes, it affects me too" at the top of the page. This will be counted. You can log on to Launchpad with your UbuntuOne ID.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is related to the graphic card, I have an intel chipset and same annoying bug! For now I installed terminal emulator "Terminator" and created a launcher with the following command in it:

terminator -e "sudo shutdown -h now"

, it works everytime and will help me wait for the right update!